# How to programmatically disable OSX from charging?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, script, battery

How can we programatically disable OSX from charging when connected to power source?
And how can we programatically check the current battery percentage?

In order to extend battery life I'd like to write a script that prevents the computer from continuosly charging when it reaches 100%, and re-enables the common behavior when it reaches 30%.

How can we programatically achieve this?

I know this is of some sort possible because my phone has a protection to do not charge above 85%, even though it is connected to the power source.

**Disclaimer**:

I edited the low level to be 30% because it looks like I was misinformed about how to extend the battery life.
But I'm still on search for tools or command line options to control the battery charging.

Comment: Lithium batteries prefer being maintained at a higher charge and deep discharges contribute significantly more wear than shallow charge cycles (e.g. from 60 to 80 or more). Many modern laptops have a mode that limits battery capacity to 60 or 80% for systems intended to be plugged in permanently that are intended to maximise battery life with minimal battery wear. I know the Surface Pro line has such a feature, I would check if Apple has such a feature.

Comment: Apparently modern macbooks may well have a mode to hold the device at 80% charge until it believes you will need the full battery charge: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407008/389108 using this should cause a lot less damage to the battery than discharging to 5% and fully charging it again. That link also has a lot of other alternative options to achieve the same.

Comment: @Mokubai - the 'smart' charging doesn't work so well on a 24/7 connection, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

1. AFAIK, automatically limiting charging is entirely **hardware** dependent.
2. Your plan to continually deep-cycle the battery between 5% and 100% charge is a quick way to **destroy** almost any battery, of *any* cell chemistry, whether [Li-ion](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34731848/), NiMH or even an old [lead-acid battery](https://archive.org/download/Prt3A978-1-4419-0851-32F11/1-s2.0-S0378775396025116-main.pdf)! Among other things, that causes dendrites to grow and short the cell, expansion and contraction of the electrodes, with concomitant shedding (spalling) of active material, and permanent changes to the chemicals of the electrodes that reduce ability to hold charge.

Most warranties will **not** cover battery damage due to abuse through deep cycling. If possible, keep the battery at a constant charge level, somewhere between 60% and 80%, for longest service life.

Comment: It looks like I'm very badly informed about how to extend battery life ^^,
although I tried to collect some opinions about this subject.

Either way I'd like to create a script or use something that already exists for achieving the goal there. Do you know any tools?

Answer (score 1):

100 down to 5% would be a poor profile for battery life. 80 to 30 would be better.
The Mac already has built-in optimised charging [& will never over-charge], which learns from your habits, but for 24/7 connection there is a 3rd party app [AlDente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente) which will maintain between defined charge percentages.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting information. As I commented above it looks like I'm very misinformed how to extend my batter life. I'll check this AlDente tool, it looks interesting.

It looks like I need to exchange my research or create another question to collect articles and benchmark tests on how to maximize the battery life as much as possible.